# Algorithm to order array

Tags: java, c#, algorithms

Take for example this input array:

```
[2,7,1,4,9]
```

For this input, I need to produce an array of total 23 elements which contains two elements of 2, seven elements of 7, one element of 1, four elements of 4 and nine elements of 9.
Example of output array:

```
[2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1,4,4,4,4,9,...]
```

However, this array **needs to be ordered in the way that minimizes the number of same elements appearing next to each other**. The example of such array would be something like this:

```
[7,2,9,4,9,1,7,...]
```

The primary goal is to minimize the number of the same adjacent elements.

Secondary goal is to distribute elements unbiased across resulting array if possible.

Any pseudo code or C#, java, ... would be helpful.

Comment: You apparently care a lot about the shuffle *not* being random (or at least, not randomly chosen from *all* permutations but only from those fulfilling a specific criteria). Is that an actual business requirement, or are you just scared of random numbers? ;-)

Comment: I am reading about that algorithm, but it seems it is just a plain random shuffler, does not minimize the same adjacent elements.

Comment: @delnan yes it is a business requirement. Take for example a DJ which needs to play song A 10 times, song B 5 times and song C 7 times, ... but he needs an algorithm to make order of songs in such way that no same song is played twice in a row (if possible).

Comment: @Dusan you may be interested in [I'd like to write an “ultimate shuffle” algorithm to sort my mp3 collection](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194480/id-like-to-write-an-ultimate-shuffle-algorithm-to-sort-my-mp3-collection) which specifically addresses the DJ problem.

Comment: @Dusan - with 57 views on your question, you have no idea who has up voted or down voted.  Voting on SE is intentionally anonymous by design.  I doubt gnat wasted a down vote on your question, but your response merely encourages others to downvote and then _not_ leave a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be seen as a [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms):

- each element is a node of your graph, labled with it's number
- there are edges between each pair of nodes
- the "distance" of getting from one node to another is 0 if the lables have different numbers, and 1 if the numbers are equal

Now you are looking for a route through this graph minimizing the total distance. Google for

```
           traveling salesman <your_favorite_programming_language>
```

and you will find tons of example implementations with heuristic or brute-force approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you suggest some decent heuristic for this specific 0-1 graph which is expected to work less than a second for the max 100 elements in the resulting array?

Comment: @Dusan: no, but I suggest you implement one of the simpler suggestions from the Wikipedia article about TSP and test if it is good enough for your case.

Answer (score 1):

The resulting array only really needs to separate the largest elements, any smaller element will be trivially separated by the larger elements. So if we have 9, 7, 4, and 2:

```
999999999
9797979797979799
97 97 97 97 97 97 97 94 9
```

And now it's easy, because there are always enough spaces to insert smaller numbers (starting at the left)

```
974 974 974 972 972 97 97 94 9
```